# Can not pass custom data on click event

Tags: jquery

Why can't I pass custom data on click event?? I always get error message `direction is not defined`

Here is my code:

```
function siblingPagination(page){
        var el = $('.post-pagination > ul > li > .page-numbers:contains("' + page + '")').parent();

        var list =  {
            prev : el.prev().find('.page-numbers'),
            next : el.next().find('.page-numbers')
        };

        $.each( list, function(key){
            $(this).addClass(key);
            $(this).on('click',{direction: key}, function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop   : $('.js-load-more.' + event.data.direction + '').offset().top-30
                }, 'slow');
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Replace event.data.direction by e.data.direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `event.data.direction` by `e.data.direction`